# How to get the value for Control inside FormArray in Angular while displaying record for patchValue operation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I've been using FormArray in angular reactive form, and everything works just fine until I try to do **patchValue()** operation.

Here, I try to edit **projectForm**. In the form you can add multiple **developers** from `<select> <option> </option> </select>`. Value in the option field are from the database and the user can add any numbers of **developers** as he/she wants.

Simplified Code version of the problem is as below:
`project.component.ts`

```js
projectForm: FormGroup

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private projectService: ProjectService, private developerService: DeveloperService){ }

ngOnInit() {
    this.developerService.getDeveloper().subscribe((data) => {
        this.developers = data;
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
    } 
    });

    this.projectForm = this.fb.group({
        project_name: [''],
        devs: this.fb.array([this.buildDevs()]),
    })
    this.editProject();
}

buildDevs(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      developer: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

displayProject(id: number) {
    this.projectService.getProjectDetail(id).subscribe(
        (project) => this.editProject(project),
        (error) => console.log(error)
    )
}

editProject(project){
    this.projectForm.patchValue({
       project_name: project.project_name, 
    });
    this.projectForm.setControl('devs', this.fb.array(project.developer || []));
}
```

`ProjectService` is responding with correct project response. Nothing wrong in there.
**Add** and **update** post need to be done in same form, and adding the form is working fine.
`project.component.html'

```html
<form [formGroup]="projectForm">

    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="project_name">

    <label> Developers: </label>
    <div formArrayName="devs">
        <div *ngFor="let d of projectForm.controls.devs.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
             <select formControlName="developer" *ngIf="developers">
               <option *ngFor="let dev of developers" value="{{ dev.id }}">{{ dev.user.username }}
               </option> 
             </select>   
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`Following error in the console is present in the response whenever I visit the project edit route`
[image: error seen in the console]
The option field number are exact with the number of developers associated with the project want to be edited but the username of the developer is not seen in the option.
`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'devs -> 0 -> developer'`
`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'devs -> 1 -> developer'`
`so on ... as the number of developer ...`
Any help will be appreciated as I am new to angular and tried all possible options that I can do. Thank you.

Comment: Replace  in HTML projectForm.controls.devs.controls with "devs.controls". It will be useful if you provide stackblitz with such queries. It will help other developers to find issue quickly and resolve it faster for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize `FormArray` with required number of controls before using `patchValue`.

assuming `project.developer` is an `Array of Objects` in this form based on your code

```
[{developer: "dev1"},{developer: "dev2"},{developer: "dev3"}]
```

```
  editProject(project) {
    const devs = this.projectForm.get("devs") as FormArray;
    devs.clear();
    project.developer.forEach(d => devs.push(this.buildDevs()));
    this.projectForm.patchValue({
      project_name: project.project_name,
      devs: project.developer
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am using this in `<select> </select` field and using this solution, the exact number of  `<select> </select>` field is displayed without any error but the value is not selected, I think the value of `id` from the response is needed to show the selected field value.

Comment: The response is in format   ```[{id: 1, detail: 'detail-1'}, {id:2, detail: 'detail-2'}]```

Comment: then convert it to the format your form expects as follows `devs: project.developer.map(pd => ({developer: pd.id}))`

Comment: i am glad that it helped. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used `patchModelValue` method of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators`, it will update the value of the FormControl inside the FormGroup based on provided server JSON object or model object. It will update the particular FormControl's value from the FormGroup. You can pass the project.developer during your edit project api call.

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    userInfoFormGroup: RxFormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.userInfoFormGroup = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.group({      
          devs:[
          {
            developer:['',Validators.required]
          }]
        });
    }
 getFormArray(){
      let formarray = this.userInfoFormGroup.controls.devs as FormArray;
      return formarray.controls;
    }

    editProject()
    {
          this.userInfoFormGroup.patchModelValue( {
                devs: [{ developer: "John" }] });
    }
}
```

You just need to import `RxFormBuilder` in your component and `RxReactiveFormsModule` in your app module ts

Please refer this [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmc4f6)

Comment: I am really new at Angular, and I do not know much about patchModelValue, my problem is now fixed after following another answer. Your help is appreciated, thank you :)